# Google calendar API calls blocked by captcha

Tags: asp.net, google-api

I have successfully written a tool to display upcoming calendar events on a website using Google's calendar API (v2).  I am using the username/password method outlined at https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v2/developers_guide_dotnet#AuthClientLogin.  Today an instance of this code would not return data or a decent error message.  I finally logged into the web server and browsed directly to http://calendar.google.com and logged in using the credentials.  I was challenged by Google's captcha and then my code worked.

How do I get around API calls being blocked by Google's captcha security?  I don't want to have to re-code for magic cookies but I will if I have to.  I have read some about generating tokens but I dont know if that is something I have to do once or every time the code is called.

Answer (score 0):

If your app is a service that is getting used by many people, you might be running into API call bandwidth limitation. That is, google is limiting the number of API requests per time interval.

If this IS getting used by many people, you may have to upgrade to a paid account.

Comment: I will have to check on that.  That might be an issue.  I am using v2 api and it requires a unique api key.